# How do I get a bigger bag?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I love picking stuff up in the forest and the like, but now that I have a cow and fish traps and all of that sort of thing, I find that I often run out of space in my bag pretty fast.

I know I can just make trips back to my house to store things or go and ship things, but it takes time to go back and forth.

Is there a way to get a bigger backpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hana](http://fogu.com/hm11/shops/general-store.php), at the General Store will sell you your first Backpack Upgrade in your first summer, and your second upgrade in your first fall/autumn (after you've purchase the first Backpack Upgrade).

You start with 30 slots, which can be upgraded to 50 slots. Then 80 slots.

Be careful not to carry too many building supplies (like lumber) early on as there's no place in the house to store them.

Comment: 50 slots is the max?

Comment: @fbueckert I think 80 is the max. I only have the first upgrade at the moment. I haven't had issues with bag space since you have 100 slots in your fridge, item bin, and tool bin. I believe they can all be upgraded via blueprints.